# How to use java classes in React Native?

Tags: java, react-native

I have an api for java. Is there a way to use them in react native? I want to be able to call and use these methods.

This is the link for api in case it's helpful for an idea: https://bag.org.tr/proje/nixar_shared/nixar_api_java

Thank you

Comment: An API is basically an HTTP server which can be done in many language, **then** is can be called by a client in several language too

Comment: How can I use these java methods in react native?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Intro to native modules](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-intro), you need to create a native module that can pass data between your react native code and the java code.

Comment: My java code doesn't have @ReactMethod as in the examples. Do I need to change all methods like this from the java code?

Comment: I would write your own native module that makes calls to the nixar java api. Basically write a native module that wrap around the lib you want to use. I wouldnt change the existing lib. Check out https://medium.com/wix-engineering/creating-a-native-module-in-react-native-93bab0123e46